# Acrobat Reader Issue with saving files to redirected drives in terminal server

Tags: adobe-reader, adobe-reader-dc

I have 2 Terminal servers with different reader versions, 1 has Adobe reader XI and the other has Acrobat Reader DC version 2019.010.20098

When I login to the server with XI and I want to save a file from the program to a redirected drive I have no problems. However, when I try the same on the server with DC I get this alert: "The document could not be saved, access denied".

On the problematic server I am able to save files to that location by copying and pasting or even from office apps saving new \ existing files to the redirected location.

Also, these servers are used to work with SAP. On the problematic server, when a user tries to save a file from SAP to the redirected drive it gets the alert about "disk used for temporary files is full".

I tried asking this question in adobe forum without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you have found the solution yet but I'm fairly certain that your issue is related to the following discussion on technet - which also has the solution

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86f3ca6b-f780-4618-a595-9818ab36bb4b/rds-servers-events-7011-7046-bsod-rdbsssys?forum=winserverTS

You have to create a new DWORD value named "bEnableProtectedModeAppContainer" under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureLockDown"

Value = "0" (zero)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks for this will check